# ERROR: gcloud crashed (ArgumentError): argument USER_ARGS: unrecognized args: --runtime_version=1.0

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Below script was running fine until yesterday morning.

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training "$JOB_ID" \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --package-path trainer \
  --staging-bucket "$BUCKET" \
  --region us-central1 \
  --runtime_version=1.0 \
  -- \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/training" \
  --eval_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval*" \
  --train_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/train*" \
  --classification_type "multilabel" \
```

Running into below error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ArgumentError): argument USER_ARGS: unrecognized args: --runtime_version=1.0
The '--' argument must be specified between gcloud specific args on the left and USER_ARGS on the right.
```

Below are the gcloud components version:

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 147.0.0
alpha 2016.01.12
app-engine-go 
app-engine-go-linux-x86_64 1.9.50
app-engine-java 1.9.50
app-engine-php " "
app-engine-python 1.9.50
beta 2016.01.12
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
cloud-datastore-emulator 1.2.1
core 2017.03.13
alpha 2016.01.12
core-nix 2016.11.07
datalab 20170309
datalab-nix 20170105
gcd-emulator v1beta3-1.0.0
gcloud 
gcloud-deps 2017.03.13
gcloud-deps-linux-x86_64 2017.02.21
gsutil 4.22
gsutil-nix 4.18
kubectl 
kubectl-linux-x86_64 1.5.3
pubsub-emulator 2017.02.07
```

Not sure whether this is anything changed in Cloud, or I need check any config on my end that may cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for the report. We'll investigate. Out of curiousity, does it work if you leave the --runtime_version flag off? (The default is 1.0)

Comment: I changed the --runtime_version=1.0 to --runtime-version=1.0 and it is working now. I issued a gcloud crash report yesterday and just got back from them that "runtime_version" is the name of a flag that gcloud respects. They have recently replaced the warning to error for unrecognized argument. It may also imply that without --runtime-version, the default runtime-version 1.0 works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use --runtime-version as the name of the argument (hyphen instead of underscore).

Without that, gcloud is assuming its some custom user-defined argument, which it expects to be in the list after the '--', hence the confusing error message.